# Get List<int> from List<Customer> using linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I have list of `customer` and want its `id` in separate list `List<int>`.

I tried using:

```
customerList.Cast<int>.Distinct().ToList()
```

But it dosn't work. I also want distinct customer int list.

How can I do that using `LINQ` syntax? What changes should I do in my query?

Comment: can you show some code of what you have tried, atleast the properties of Customer class would be fine

Comment: Although the OP could have been a little more descriptive, I did not fins this question vague at all. I knew exactly what he wanted to do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<int> customerIds = customerList.Select(c => c.Id).Distinct().ToList();
```

The code assumes that your customer object has an Id property which returns an int.

Answer (score 10):

Select the ID from your Customer List and then use [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to get a list of Ids.

```
var IdList = customerList.Select(r=> r.ID).ToList();
```

To get distinct Ids try:

```
var IdList = customerList.Select(r=> r.ID).Distinct().ToList();
```